# Do multiple dimensions exist?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

I came up with this line somewhere:

> *To properly experience $n$ dimensions the retina of the organism should be at least of $n-1$ dimensions.*
>
> *And human eye has $2$ dimensional retina, so we can experience at most 3 dimensions properly.*

Now my question is:

1. Do more than 3 dimensions exist?
2. What is the proof that 'there exist only 3' or 'more dimensions do exist'?

Comment: Unrelated to dimensions, but multiple instances of "do" in your title do exist.

Comment: I doubt this assertion. Our 2-dimensional retina can by no means observe the third dimension, as is demonstrated with lots of optical illusions. We only have a 2-dimensional projection to work with which can be the result of an infinite number of 3-dimensional arrangements. With **two** eyes/retinas the situation is different but one could argue that the resulting overall optical system is actually 3-dimensional.

Comment: On the contrary I would contend that in order to fully observe 3-dimensional objects including their insides one needs an 4-dimensional retina, or at least one with 3 dimensions of which one is orthogonal to the dimensions of the object. *We* as 3-D beings can fully grok a surface, but another surface in the same plane as the observed one could not. Same with 3 dimensions. In order to look *inside* a body you need another dimension.

Comment: It's interesting to note that jumpings spiders have several retina layers, so the are three-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose we could add time as a 4th. However, apart from that there is no experimental evidence whatsoever for more than 3 spacial dimensions. String Theory and its friends remain theories with negligible experimental evidence in their favor.

Comment: Well this makes me feel, whats that thing which travels along this dimension

Comment: And if time is considered the 4th dimension, then the retina is actually 3-dimensional, and indeed we can observe 3-dimensional objects traveling through time, with us ;-).